# Are there any conflicts between how Jesus is described in the Book of Mormon vs how He is described in the Bible?

Tags: life-of-jesus, lds

I'm interested in knowing if there are any conflicts between the Book of Mormon's Jesus and the Bible's Jesus. Are their natures different? Is what they commanded different? I'm looking for any supporting text that would reveal to me whether the the Book of Mormon does or does not speak about the same Jesus Christ that the Bible talks about.

Any denomination may answer.

Comment: Let's try to keep in mind that the OP is looking for similarities or differences between references of Christ in the Book of Mormon and te Bible and NOT the 'Mormon Jesus' and the 'Jesus' of other faiths.

Comment: Well stated Kronos.

Comment: I think [Doctrine and Covenants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_and_Covenants) and [Pearl of Great Price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_of_Great_Price_(Latter_Day_Saints)) should be included in the question and used in the answers, if they say anything about Jesus at all. I think D&C would.

Answer (score 7):

By simply limiting this answer to the similarities of the Book of Mormon and the Bible here is what I've put together (note this is in no way a complete compilation of the similarities but rather a starting point):

```
|   Doctrine                |      Book of Mormon   |      Bible (KJV)      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                           |                       |                       |
|1. Jesus was born of Virgin|       Alma 7:9-10     |       Matthew 1:16    |
|   Mary                    |                       |                       |
|                           |                       |                       |
|2. He institued the        |     3 Nephi 18        |       Matthew 26      |
|   Sacrament for His       |                       |                       |
|   followers               |                       |                       |
|                           |                       |                       |
|3. The resurected Christ   |    3 Nephi 11:14-15   |       John 20: 26-27  |
|   had scars he showed his |                       |                       |
|   believers               |                       |                       |
|                           |                       |                       |
|4. Christ taught similar   |    3 Nephi 12         |       Matthew 5       |
|   doctrines               |                       |                       |
|                           |                       |                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*I will try to update as I find more*

Answer (score 0):

One conflict is that the teachings of the Mormons differ from some verses in the Book of Mormon.  So, the question is not completely relevant.  The Mormons teaching about Jesus is that both Jesus and God the Father were once men on another planet who attained godhood by being good Mormons there.  This is the doctrine of eternal progression.  "As man is, so God once was; as God is, so man can become."

The Book of Mormon appears to be even more explicitly Trinitarian than the Bible.  However, Joseph Smith seems to have changed his doctrines after the publishing of the Book of Mormon, but perhaps embraced this earlier on.  Today, the Mormons do not believe anything close to the Trinity.

So, the Book of Mormon does have some things that appear to correspond to Trinitarian theology, yet the LDS church does not hold to the Trinity.

**Book of Mormon References**

> And now, behold, my beloved brethren, this is the away; and there is
>   none other way nor name given under heaven whereby man can be saved in
>   the kingdom of God. And now, behold, this is the doctrine of Christ,
>   and the only **and true doctrine of the Father, and of the Son, and of
>   the Holy Ghost, which is one God, without end**. Amen.  2 Nephi 31:21
>
> And now Abinadi said unto them: I would that ye should understand that
>   God himself shall come down among the children of men, and shall
>   redeem his people.And because he dwelleth in flesh he shall be called
>   the Son of God, and having subjected the flesh to the will of the
>   Father, being the Father and the Son—The Father, because he was
>   conceived by the power of God; and the Son, because of the flesh; thus
>   becoming the Father and Son—**And they are one God**, yea, the very
>   Eternal Father of heaven and of earth. And thus the flesh becoming
>   subject to the Spirit, or the Son to the Father, **being one God**,
>   suffereth temptation, and yieldeth not to the temptation, but
>   suffereth himself to be mocked, and scourged, and cast out, and
>   disowned by his people.  Mosiah 15:1-5
>
> Now, this restoration shall come to all, both old and young, both bond
>   and free, both male and female, both the wicked and the righteous; and
>   even there shall not so much as a hair of their heads be lost; but
>   every thing shall be restored to its perfect frame, as it is now, or
>   in the body, and shall be brought and be arraigned before the bar of
>   **Christ the Son, and God the Father, and the Holy Spirit, which is one Eternal God,** to be judged according to their works, whether they
>   be good or whether they be evil.  Alma 11:44
>
> And after this manner shall ye baptize in my name; for behold, verily
>   I say unto you, that **the Father, and the Son, and the Holy Ghost are
>   one**; and I am in the Father, and the Father in me, and the Father
>   and I are one. . . . And thus will the Father bear record of me, and
>   the Holy Ghost will bear record unto him of the Father and me; **for
>   the Father, and I, and the Holy Ghost are one.**  3 Nephi 11:27, 36
>
> And he hath brought to pass the redemption of the world, whereby he
>   that is found guiltless before him at the judgment day hath it given
>   unto him to dwell in the presence of God in his kingdom, to sing
>   ceaseless praises with the choirs above, unto **the Father, and unto the
>   Son, and unto the Holy Ghost, which are one God**, in a state of
>   happiness which hath no end.  Mormon 7:7
>
> As well as those who should come after, who should believe in the
>   agifts and callings of God by the Holy Ghost, which bbeareth record of
>   the Father and of the Son;  **Which Father, Son, and Holy Ghost are
>   one God, infinite and eternal, without end**. Amen.  Doctrines and
>   Covenants 20:27-28

Comment: Can you back this up with some references? How do you determine that the teachings of Mormons are different from there own source texts? What did Joseph Smith write after the Book of Mormon that shows evidence of a changed view about Jesus?

Comment: I think this answer does indeed show conflicts in the Mormon Jesus and the Christian Jesus.

Comment: Please add sources if possible.

Comment: The main teachings of Mormons come from the Doctrines and Covenants and the Pearl of Great Price--not the Book of Mormon.  I've read several books about Mormons who have left the church.  In those books, they discuss the teachings of Mormonism.  I would recommend The God Makers, Beyond Mormonism, Leaving the Saints, Mormonism Mama and Me, A Mormon's Unexpected Journey, and By His Own Hand Upon Papyrus.

Comment: The problem with doing that @Narnian is you're reading texts from people who generally have left the Mormon faith with a bad taste in their mouth, and therefore are biased. The best thing to do when researching ANY religion is to go to their own doctrine and compare there.

Comment: @KronoS So, do you dispute this?  Mormons have a meat and milk idea, that they withhold the "meat" of their doctrine from outsiders, giving them only "milk".  The problem is that the "meat" is the true doctrines of the church.

Comment: Let's try to remember what exactly this site and the question is for. The OP is asking for differences or similarities between the Bible and the Book of Mormon in regard to their accounting of Christ. This site is meant to be a source of informational understanding of the Christian doctrine and Christian sects. Let's not get into a debate of these religions but rather discuss their doctrine and practices.

Comment: My answer does that, but also mentions that the Book of Mormon's teachings about Jesus are not representative of Mormon beliefs. That's pertinent information.

Comment: I've read the Book of Mormon and from what I can tell the teachings about Jesus are spot on in relation to LDS beliefs.  Again, references would help your cause greatly.

Comment: They don't teach that Jesus attained Godhood on another planet.

Comment: As a devout Latter-Day Saint I'm quite confused to hear that we believe in a different Jesus than the Book of Mormon and that the scriptures we really focus on are from the Doctrine and Covenants and Pearl of Great Price...

Comment: @Zannjaminderson The Book of Mormon teaches that there is one God--not many Gods (Alma 11:27-39, 44 and more), that God is Spirit rather than having a physical body (Alma 18:26-28, 22:8-11), that man did no have a pre-existence (Jacob 4:9, Alma 18:28, 34-36), that there is a heaven and hell instead of three types of glory (2 Nephi 28:22 and more), polygamy is condemned rather than commanded (Jacob 1:15; 2:24; 3:5)... and more.

Comment: @Narnian have you actually read the Book of Mormon or have you merely gotten those references from the the books you listed which as mentioned were written by people who might not be completely fair in their view of the LDS church? Having read the Book of Mormon multiple times, And as someone who reads from it everyday I can tell you sir that your views are in fact false.

Comment: @Narnian Those are wonderful examples of taking a single passage out of context and getting it to mean something completely different. If you would like to understand what any of those passages actually mean feel free to post a question like you have so many in the past. I believe "How does <insert form of Christianity> interpret <insert passage>?" are within the scope of this site. Because the way you are interpreting them is not what is taught by the church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints.

Comment: @Narnian. Great, so you *do* have references (even if they've been disputed). Why not edit those references into your answer?

Comment: @TRiG I meant to do this quite awhile ago...  Thanks for the request.

Answer (score 0):

There are abundant sources on the internet about the Mormon Jesus.  I'd recommend starting with [this CRI page.](http://www.equip.org/perspectives/what-is-the-difference-between-the-mormon-jesus-and-the-jesus-of-the-bible) An excerpt:

> ...The Bible teaches that Jesus has always existed as God (John 1:1), Mormons see Jesus as someone who worked His way up to godhood.  In fact, to Mormons, Jesus is merely one in purpose with God the Father; whereas the Bible declares that the Father and the Son are also one in essence (cf. Phil. 2:6) — that they are both equally God and members of the Holy Trinity.

Comment: Mormons don't see Christ as 'someone who worked His way up to godhood' but rather the literal Son of God.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Mormons see us all as "literal sons of God" in the same way as Jesus, and Jesus was at first a man who became a god in the same way we might.

Comment: Actually the Mormon doctrine teaches that we are all "Spiritual Sons and Daughters of God" while Jesus Christ was the "literal" meaning both spiritual and physical Son of God.

Comment: KronoS is absolutely right regarding this.